# Controles Personalizados em vb .net

Tags: vb.net, controles

Como criar controles personalizados em vb .net?

Gostaria de cria-los e modificar valores de suas propriedades.
Minha finalidade é de importá-los em outros projetos.

Comment: Só criar uma classe que estenda/herde o controle. Por exemplo: **`Public Class TextBoxPersonalizado Inherits TextBox`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é fácil. Existem várias possibilidades, dentre elas:

### Usando um `UserControl` *// a maneira mais fácil*

É bem simples criar um conjunto de controles, como talvez uma listinha com alguns botões predefinidos ou talvez um único controle. Você sempre poderá acessar as propriedades do seu controle se forem públicos e visíveis para o Designer.

```
Public Class MeuControle
     Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

     ' Propriedade interna             
     Private Dim _CorDeFundo As Color

     <DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute()>
     Public Property CorDeFundo As Color
           Get
                 Return _CorDeFundo
           End Get
           Set (value As Color)
                 _CorDeFundo = value
           End Set
     End Property
     ...
     ...
```

No código acima, a propriedade `CorDeFundo` não altera nada no código, ela só está ali para indicar que há uma propriedade no designer que altera a cor de fundo. Para mostrar no designer essa propriedade, adicione o atributo [`DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) em cima do método como está acima.

Aprenda sobre os `UserControl` [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

### Herdando um `Control` diretamente *// criar um controle do zero*

Aqui é um pouco mais complicado, você não vai usar o designer para desenhar seu controle, irá usar tudo à base de validações do controle, terá que implementar uma classe que herda o tipo `System.Windows.Forms.Control` e terá que emular os eventos (quase todos) como `MouseDown`, `OnPaint` (o que mais será usado), `Focused`, etc.

Uma dica que te dou, é procurar vários exemplos no [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/), lá o pessoal desenvolve bastantes controles.

Também dá uma olhada nesse [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996443.aspx) (somente em inglês).

---

### Criando controles a partir de controles

Como o **@LINQ** disse, é herdando controles em sua classe. Por exemplo, você pode alterar a cor da seleção de uma `ListBox` com este código:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem
    e.DrawBackground()
    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightSeaGreen, e.Bounds)
    End If
    Using b As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(e.Index)), e.Font, b, e.Bounds)
    End Using
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub
```

---

Em suma, não é fácil se você quiser fazer um controle do zero, sem usar nenhum outro controle como base. Fica mais fácil ainda usando UserControls.